# implicit_plot maxima windows doesn't show an image

Tags: maxima

Here is my code:

```
implicit_plot([x=-log(y),x=-sqrt(y),y=0,y=1,y=%e],[x,-5,5],[y,-5,5]);
```

That's what goes after I press shift+enter:

```
(%o258) implicit_plot([x=-log(y),x=-sqrt(y),y=0,y=1,y=%e],[x,-5,5],[y,-5,5])
```

This code just doesn't execute! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, finally found out myself, I should have write

```
load(implicit_plot);
```